# onchange() function not defined (inaccessible from index.html?)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, webpack, ecmascript-6

i am assigning an 'onchange' attribute to a `<select>` tag in my html. I have done so successfully in my main.js file (which is bundled into bundle.js). My bundle.js is then referenced in the index.html.

Whenever the onchange event tries to use the function i have defined 
 `filterChanged()`, it provides a reference error: "filterChanged is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange"

i originally thought it may be due to the function not being a global variable, so i assigned to to a `var` and the issue persists.

see below the code -

main.js

```
var filterChanged = function() {
    console.log('filter changed');
}

window.onload = function() {
    let filter = document.getElementById('filter-list');
    filter.setAttribute('onchange', 'filterChanged()');
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TestProj</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="build/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Todos</h3>
    <p>Number of items to show</p>
    <select id="filter-list" name="filter">
            <option selected="true" value="list10">10</option>
            <option value="list20">20</option>
            <option value="list30">30</option>
    </select>
    <ul id="todo_list">
        <!-- Inject list here with JS (main.js getTodos()) -->
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use different ways.
First way adding onchange to your select:

```
<select id="filter-list" name="filter" onchange="filterChanged();">
```

Second way using eventListener:

```
filter.addEventListener('change', filterChanged);
```

Third way :

```
window.onload=function() {
  let filter = document.getElementById('filter-list');
  filter.onchange=function() {
    // The code of your function
  } 
}
```

Comment: i tried the first method (adding onchange to the select in html) which didn't work for me before. However, the event listener method works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Please use:

```
filter.addEventListener("change", filterChanged);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this:

```
filter.setAttribute('onchange', 'filterChanged()');
```

but do:

```
filter.addEventListener('change', filterChanged);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is common format to addEventListener()

```
object.addEventListener("change", myScript);
```

so update your code

```
filter.setAttribute('onchange', 'filterChanged()');
```

to

```
filter.addEventListener('change', filterChanged);
```

for more information

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

Answer (score 1):

this will work, you don't need to define anything in <select, just the id (so jquery can find it)

> $("#filter-list").on("change", filterChanged);
>
> function filterChanged() { 
> //it just an example of a defined function
> **var_x = this.value**;
> **other_function()**;
>  console.log('filter changed');
> }

or

> $("#filter-list").on("change", function() { 
> // if you want to set
> **var_x = this.value**;
> // or call a **function()**;
> console.log('filter changed');
> });

/*------------------------------------------------------------*/

none of the ways below will work:

> <select id='filter-list' onchange:'"+filterChanged()+"'>

or

> <select id='filter-list' onchange:'filterChanged'>

or this

> <select id='filter-list' onchange:'filterChanged()'>

or this

> <select id='filter-list' onchange:'$(filterChanged())'>